# Allowing users to run an SSRS 2008 R2 report directly instead of creating a report viewer within a website

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've worked with this before in another job where the DBA set up user access to certain reports in SSRS.

All I had to do was to provide a link to the SSRS home page and the user would try and drill down to click on the report and run it. If they didn't have access (which the DBA sets up), they wouldn't be able to even get into the folder that contains the reports or at worst not being able to run the specific report.

Can someone please help me to inform my co-workers (thorugh a link, etc) how easy this can be accomplished instead of setting up a report viewer page within an application to access the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about the Report Manager website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147(v=sql.105).aspx

This is configured during the Reporting Services install or through the Reporting Services Configuration Manager. This only involves setting up the report URL; typically a once and done operation.

In terms of setting up access, you need to to grant access to items (e.g. Folders and Reports) in the Report Server - the exact steps are in this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034(v=sql.105).aspx

1. Start Report Manager and locate the report item for which you want
   to add a user or group.
2. Hover over the item, and click the drop-down arrow.
3. In the drop-down menu, click Security.
4. Click New Role Assignment.
5. In Group or user name, enter a Windows domain user or group account
   in this format: < domain >\< account >. If you are using forms
   authentication or custom security, specify the user or group account
   in the format that is correct for your deployment.
6. Select one or more role definitions that describe how the user or
   group should access the item, and then click OK.

So there's not much to it - up to your organisation how you'd like to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

OK,

Follow those steps

1. Login to your report manager with administrator permision http://{ServerName}/Reports
2. Click on the arrow next to the "Home" folder and than click on security
   [image]
3. Click on "New Role Assignment"
4. In the "Group or User name" write a user name and check the permissions you want to set for him

Note: you should write a user that exist in your organization

For example write everyone (to give everyone access to the report server) with permission of "Browser"

[image]